# from df.to_json and want to replace None with NaN (python)

Tags: python, json, pandas, nan

I convert my dataframe into json type with:

```
df_json = df.to_json(orient = "records")
```

but with this way, my NaN column is converted as None while I actually expect them to be NaN. So, when I proceed my dataframe to postgres, the NaN column will be read and extracted as NULL.

the result when I convert my dataframe:

```
no   type
1    All
2    None
3    None
```

while, the desired result:

```
no   type
1    All
2    NaN
3    NaN
```

So far, I have tried:

```
df_json = df.to_json(orient = "records").replace("None", np.NaN)
```

but I got error `replace() argument 2 must be str, not float`

how can I convert the `None` to be NaN?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If need `json`, there are no `NaN/None`s, there are converted to `null`s.

Possible alternative si use `dictionary` with replace `None`s to `NaN`s first:

```
df_dict = df.mask(df.isna(), np.nan).to_dict(orient = "records")
print (df_dict)
[{'no': 1, 'type': 'All'}, {'no': 2, 'type': nan}, {'no': 3, 'type': nan}]
```

If `None` is string:

```
df_dict = df.replace("None", np.NaN).to_dict(orient = "records")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried the first answer, it gave me error ```the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list```

Comment: @nomnom3214 - sure, but if `NaN` in json, then json is not valid.